# Android: programmatically added layout ignores theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have abstract `UltraSuperActivity` inherited by abstract `SuperActivity` inherited by `MyActivity`. In `OnCreate` of `SuperActivity` I call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_super);` which contains `HorizontalScrollLayout` into which I add the layout of current activity

I add layout like this in `OnCreate` in `MyActivity`:

```
LinearLayout activity_layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, null);
HorizontalScrollView application_contents = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.application_contents);
HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams cp = new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
some more code...
application_contents.addView(activity_layout, cp);
```

Inflater is set up in `UltraSuperActivity` as static:

```
if(inflater == null){
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.setFactory(CustomViewFactory.getInstance()); // we add our factory for our views
}
```

I am using `MyButton` style which as a theme is given to every button. That works in `activity_super` layout but it does not work in `activity_layout` and it is displayed as common Android button. Theme is set in `AndroidManifest.xml`. If I add `MyButton` style in the `activity_layout` to the button it works but I don't understand why it does not use the set up theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are not getting your activity theme, rather you are getting the application theme, which in this case is most likely the default. Try replacing getApplicationContext() with getContext() (or "this"). A common mistake is to think the Application Context and an Activity Context are the same thing.

Comment: inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); did the magic :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the proper `inflate` method. You should use `inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)` where the ViewGroup is not null. Read this article for more information on the matter:

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: I changed the inflater to use LinearLayout activity_layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.application_contents), false); but it does not have any effect, am I doing it wrong?